# plateforms to develop private blockchain

Tags: blockchain

**plateforms to develop private blockchain**

Hello !

I want to develop a **private** **blockchain** , and i wanna know what's the best **plateforms** / logiciel to work with 
thank you

Comment: IMO, this is not a duplicate question, as ABDUELLAH is not asking about setting up a private ethereum but also other platforms that allow to develop private blockchain.

Comment: yes exactly @PrashantPrabhakarSingh

Comment: anyway thank you both of you atomh33ls & PrashantPrabhakarSingh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you actually want, but this may help.

There are multiple platforms which allow you to build private blockchain.There are some platforms that allow you to build a private and/or Public blockChain. You can have a look to some of them:

1. [MultiChain](http://www.multichain.com/)
2. [HydraChain](http://hydrachain.com/)
3. [Eris](https://erisindustries.com/)
4. [OpenChain](https://www.openchain.org/)
5. [Chain](https://chain.com/)

IMO, MutiChain is a good platform, you can start exploring. It uses bitcoin protocol ion backend. Also have a loook to OpenChain, if it satisfies your need.